# Hook path in main menu not hold active trail

Tags: routes

In custom module names supply_area I've created custom path.

```
function supply_area_menu() {
    $items['supply-area'] = array(
        'title' => 'Supply area',
        'page callback' => 'supply_area_page',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'access callback' => true,
        'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    );
    return $items;
}
```

Everything works perfectly except that even if I assign this path into main menu structure it does not hold menu structure so breadcrumbs looks like:
Home > Supply area and not Home > About > Supply area.
Is there something wrong with my hook_menu?

Comment: Given just the above code, why would you presume it should know about "About" ?

Comment: It's normal menu item so I think I could add this path to main menu. If it's in main menu in Home | About | Supply area so it should hold active trail?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing in a lot more areas of your system than described above, but doing the following on a d7 testbed here:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {

  array $items;

  $items['about'] = array(
    'title' => 'About',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_about_page',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
  );

  $items['supply-area'] = array(
    'title' => 'Supply area',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_supply_area_page',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
  );

  return $items;

}

function MYMODULE_about_page() {
  return 'What\'s it all about, Alfie?';
}

function MYMODULE_supply_area_page() {
  return 'Making Supplies';
}
```

...followed by clearing caches and then setting it up via the Menu UI:

[image]

...provides the following:

[image]

so I would check how you might be doing it slightly differently on your system.